# Can I use a TabBar and TabBarView as an in page widget?

Tags: tabs, flutter

In course of my exploration of the flutter framework I came across a problem, I didn't know how to solve. Can I use [TabBar](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html) in combination with [TabBarView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TabBarView-class.html) as a child of other widgets?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Turns out it works. This is the relevant code snippet:

```
new Container(
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
  child: new TabBar(
    controller: _controller,
    tabs: [
      new Tab(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
        text: 'Address',
      ),
      new Tab(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.my_location),
        text: 'Location',
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
new Container(
  height: 80.0,
  child: new TabBarView(
    controller: _controller,
    children: <Widget>[
      new Card(
        child: new ListTile(
          leading: const Icon(Icons.home),
          title: new TextField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Search for address...'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      new Card(
        child: new ListTile(
          leading: const Icon(Icons.location_on),
          title: new Text('Latitude: 48.09342\nLongitude: 11.23403'),
          trailing: new IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.my_location), onPressed: () {}),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

And this is a working example:

[image: Screenshot]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('TestProject'),
      ),
      body: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Card(
            child: new ListTile(
              title: const Text('Some information'),
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
            child: new TabBar(
              controller: _controller,
              tabs: [
                new Tab(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
                  text: 'Address',
                ),
                new Tab(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.my_location),
                  text: 'Location',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            height: 80.0,
            child: new TabBarView(
              controller: _controller,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Card(
                  child: new ListTile(
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.home),
                    title: new TextField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Search for address...'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                new Card(
                  child: new ListTile(
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.location_on),
                    title: new Text('Latitude: 48.09342\nLongitude: 11.23403'),
                    trailing: new IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.my_location), onPressed: () {}),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          new Card(
            child: new ListTile(
              title: const Text('Some more information'),
            ),
          ),
          new RaisedButton(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text(
              'Search for POIs',
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use a tabbarview inside a container without having to set a specific height? I'm getting a stuck because the children in my tabbarviews are variable height.

Comment: @Negora Ever find an answer?

Comment: it's possible but I lost my source somehow :( it can be done!

Comment: @Negora true we don't want container height there...I'm still struggling how to get rid off it

Comment: You can replace `Container` with `Expanded`.

Answer (score 6):

If you have variable height in `TabBarView`, you can use `Expanded`.

```
body:
    ...
    new Expanded(
        child: new TabBarView(
          controller: _controller,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Card(
              child: new ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.home),
                title: new TextField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Search for address...'),
                ),
              ),
            ),//Card
            .... 
            ....
          ],//Widget
        ),//TabBarView
      ),//Expanded
```